# How do I remove the x axis spacing between bars in a bar chart?

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

After changing the width to make the bars smaller, it has moved off to the sides. How do I remove the the spacing between them. Ideally, I want to center in the middle, but there seems to be no parameters in the documentation to set for it. Scaling the picture manually doesn't reduce this gap either.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

objects = ('bar1', 'bar2')
y_pos = np.arange(len(objects))
performance = [2,6] 
stds=[0.3,0.5]
plt.bar(y_pos, performance, 0.3, align='center', yerr=stds,capsize=5, alpha=0.5)
plt.xticks(y_pos, objects)
plt.ylabel('Time (seconds)')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Use `plt.figure(1, figsize=(width, height))` where `width` and `height` denote the figure size in inches,

Comment: @Flomp unfortunately, the gap still remains even with extreme values

Answer (score 6):

List `y_pos` sets position of bar to 0 and 1 then your set width to .3 and a gap is 0.7.

You have to replace `y_pos` with certain values to put your bars close to each other: the first bar has to be at `width/2` position and the second is on `1.5 * width`.
Then you have to select optimal limits of x axis with `xlim` method to centering the bars.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

objects = ('bar1', 'bar2')
w = 0.3
y_pos = (w/2.,w*1.5)
performance = [2,6] 
stds=[0.3,0.5]
plt.bar(y_pos, performance, width=w, align='center', yerr=stds,capsize=5, alpha=0.5)
plt.gca().set_xlim([-1.,1.5])
plt.xticks(y_pos, objects)
plt.ylabel('Time (seconds)')
plt.show()
```

I hope that there is more flexible and elegant solution.
[image]